# EJB @Schedule annotation set dynamic values

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, schedule

I have a @Schedule annotation added to a method.

```
@Schedule(minute = "1", hour = "*", info="Every 1 minute")
public void getStandingOrdersTimer() {
        
}
```

Here the method will run every minute in every hour. I want to pass number of minute using a variable. With out hardcoding it here in the annotation. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Timer with the TimerService.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@LocalBean
public class TimerBean {

    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        timerService.createIntervalTimer(new Date(), getMinute() * 60000
                        new TimerConfig("MyTimer", false));
    }

    private int getMinute(){
        //here your code to get the minute value from somewhere
    }

    @Timeout
    public void getStandingOrdersTimer() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: So is it not possible with EJB schedule annotation?